# Spring security does not work when I put loginpage

Tags: spring, ldap

This is my **security config**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.security.ldap.domain}")
    private String ldapDomain;

    @Value("${spring.security.ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;
//

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/about", true);
    }
```

And this is login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--错误信息：<h4 th:text="${msg}"></h4>-->
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>账号：<input type="text" name="username" value="sdad"/></p>
    <p>密码：<input type="text" name="password" value="asda."/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="登录"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Wnen I use this, it opens login page but it cant submit it. If it could submit, it would go to **/about** but it does not. And for wrong password, i see the log from LDAP.

And this is controller

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    logger.info("login");
    return "login";
}
```

I see this log also:

```
    logger.info("login");
```

But when I convert to this of security config class:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
//                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/about", true);
    }
```

it opens login page, it opens spring default form of login. So, i dont see any logs like this:

```
  logger.info("login");
```

And for wrong password, i dont see any log or for correct password. And after success login, it goes to **about**

How can i fix it? I want to use

```
      .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/about", true);
```

with ldap

and

```
  @GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    logger.info("login");
    return "login";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In login Page add action

```
 <form action="/login" method='POST'>
```

Comment: It gives error `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.` after submit, it goes to perform_login but ldap can not process login. How can i connect to ldap in performlogin? I dont submit, ldap does it